# Canceling the Python process while reading a file corrupts the file

Tags: python, file, dill

I'm having a simple process that reads and write items to files. Sometimes, if I terminate the Python process during the read ("Ctrl c" in console), the file becomes corrupted and cant be read anymore. How can I prevent this? I already have "rb" as opening mode. Perhaps I can ensure that python doesn't cancel while it is in the file opening routine?

Here's the code that reads:

```
    import dill
    results = []
    with open(self.getFile(), 'rb') as input:
        if n is not None:
            for i in range(n):
                try:
                    results.append(dill.load(input))
                except (EOFError, pickle.UnpicklingError) as e:
                    print('ERROR with reading {}'.format(self.getFile()))
                    pass
```

And, for completeness, also the writing process -- hopefully irrelevant.

```
def write(self, objects):
    with open(self.getFile(), 'wb') as output:
        for object in objects:
            dill.dump(object, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

---

The issue happened again, and now I could see the full error:

```
    results.append(dill.load(input))
  File "/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/home/x/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Remove the try-except or use "traceback.print_exc()" to see the actual error

Comment: For the file to get corrupted it needs to be written to. Reading from it will never change its contents. *Something* wrote incomplete data to that file. Is `write` executing concurrently perhaps?

Comment: Not related per se, but you're using some reserved keywords in your code - `object` and `input` are built-in names that you shouldn't use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that you are trying to dump and load multiple objects in a single file, which is not allowed. And by not allowed I mean they can exist in lists and dictionaries but not as separate objects. So the solution here is to use a list to store and retrieve the objects.

Here is you modified write function for the same

```py
def write(self, objects):
    with open(self.getFile(), 'wb') as output:
        dill.dump(objects, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

and the same way here is you read function

```py
    import dill
    with open(self.getFile(), 'rb') as input:
        results = dill.load(input)
```

Also as @Random_Davis said, it is better if you do not use the builtin object names as parameters or variables.